# Delivery optimization with limits

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I have the following problem to solve:

1. There are N cities. Each of them has some count of test samples which are needed to be processed in laboratories (labs).
2. There are M labs. They process samples, but each has limits.
3. We need to process all the samples.
4. Optimization by the distance should be used - try to process city's samples in the nearest lab.

If there will be no limits, it's easy - for each city we determine the nearest lab and use for processing samples. But if there are capacity limits, there is a possibility of overflow in certain lab, so we need to find another lab to process samples of this city (of course, this lab will be a little bit farther).

So, **the question is**: how to distribute samples flows in optimal way by distance and without overflows?

I believe this is some well-known algorithm. Could you, please, tell me at least how it's called?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at it as a [bipartite graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph), trying to [maximize the flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem):

Order the distances between the cities and the labs from closest to farthest, then iterate over the list and:

1. Move `x` samples from the city to the lab - where `x=min(max_lab_capacity, number_of_samples)`.
2. The edge between the city and the lab is now deleted. If the lab is full - then the lab node is deleted as well. If the city has all its samples taken care of - it's node is deleted.
3. Repeat #1 & #2 until all city nodes are deleted.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! This algorithm is great, but there is one additional condition I forgot to mention (updated the question): we can't split samples to be delivered into different labs. So, it possible to do only single delivery between city and lab.

Comment: On the other hand, what would happen if you used the same algorithm, but when building the graph you exclude all the edges that don't meet the requirement (a city will be connected only to labs that can fulfill the city needs). This way you get back to the classic max flow problem...

Comment: So, the problem is how to build such graph respecting optimal distances. For example, suppose we have labs L1 (10) and L2 (15). Also, there are cities C1(7), C2(8), C3(2), C4 (5). After ordering by distances we have connections C1 & C2 -> L1, and C3 & C4->L2. Now we need some algorithm, that can relink C2 to L2 and C3 to L1... And in case with many labs there will be more than one solution. So, also we need to analyze solutions and select the best one by some criteria... This problem reminds me "coins problem", when you need to select coins of different values to reach some given amount.

Comment: It seems like this is "one-dimensional binpacking algorithm with relative costs". We pack volumes (samples) into bins (labs) with matrix of costs (distances) of each sample per each lab. So, the total cost should be minimized.

Comment: I've added another question at SO because this is absolutely different problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30911736/one-dimensional-binpacking-algorithm-with-relative-costs) Thank for your answer! Marked as accepted.